# How to close a connection to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a class that create the a MongoClient inside:

```
db = MongoDB ('mydb' , 'config')
```

I am successfully able to connect to 'mydb' database and 'config' collection - but after querying the collection I do need this connection to database again. I proceed to create connection with another database and collection

```
db = MongoDB ('mapping' , 'box_details')
```

In such a case how can I close the connection to DB previously - is it that it would automatically get closed when app exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to open connection using [pymongo.MongoClient](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/index.html#pymongo.MongoClient) which will return mongo_client object. mongo_cient has instance method [close](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.close) allowing you to close connection manually.

Please see documentation about [mongo_client](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html)

Comment: Yes but if I am switching database and collection in between do I need to explicit close per-quiried database and collections

Comment: You don't have to, but it's good practice to cleanup manually.